# jQuery .animate() to change facing position of game character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a game using jQuery but using a simple example that I found made by someone else and building on top of it.

Here is the sample that i'm using: http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/04/angel-dreams-jquery-game.html

I need to change the chase() function so that when the angel chases the dream, I want to be able to use different images of the angel facing in different directions. So basically if the angel has to go up to catch the dream, it would use the image of the angel facing up. Same thing if going down, left, right and even on a slant.

I want it to look like the character (angel) is actually chasing after the dream as it will be facing the dream wherever it goes.

Here is the function that fired when the angel chases the dream:

```
 function chase(x, y, dream) {
    //angel gets the dream 
    angel.animate({
        top: y,
        left: x 
    }, 1000, function () {
        //explode the dream
        explode(x, y, dream);
        //you lose
        lose();
    });
}
```

There is nothing wrong with the example. I just need to add the feature for being able to rotate the character(angel) and face it toward the direction that it moves when it chases after the dream. (look at the sample link I provided. I need to modify that sample to do what I explained above)

I have been trying to do this for a while now but have been unsuccessful. Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I would use jquery to make the game.  Use Javascript itself. your code will be faster and more efficient.

Comment: @CBRRacer well that'll be true if the OP is as good at optimizing code as the jQuery maintainers are. Anyway, the question here is not at all clear.  What does/doesn't work?  What part of the code is causing problems?

Comment: @CBRRacer that's not true at all and would require sufficiently more coding.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code. I'm simple using the sample that I provided and adding the functionality so that the character (angel) would rotate and face toward the dream when it chases the dream. So i will have multiple images of the character (angel) facing in different direction and would like to change the image according to which way the character (angel) moves

Comment: @TerryR I find that hard to believe if you know what you are doing with Javascript since jQuery itself is just a Wrapper for javascript.  So by definition you are adding overhead on your program by using jQuery.  It may be less code you as the developer have to write BUT it probably has to go through more javascript simply because you are using jQuery.

Comment: This is a long, over-analysed argument that I'm not going to get into here.  However jQuery & jQuery UI are used by [more than half](http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript) the top 100,000 sites on the internet and with the exception of extraordinarily large data sets (certainly not applicable to this question), any performance decreases that may exist are negligible.  I think refusing to use a JS library because your preference is vanilla JS is a personal choice and it is ignorant to suggest to someone else that your way is "better", especially in this context when it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest have more than one image of the angel looking in various directions and display the one that is appropriate based on where she is headed on the screen (you'll have to determine this logic).

```
function chase(x, y, dream) {
    // if angel is going left load the "looking left" image
    //     angel.attr('src', 'angel_left.gif');

    // if angel is going right load the "looking right" image
    //     angel.attr('src', 'angel_right.gif');

    //angel gets the dream 
    angel.animate({
        top: y,
        left: x 
    }, 1000, function () {
        //explode the dream
        explode(x, y, dream);
        //you lose
        lose();
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes I know I have to use similar logic but i'm having trouble implementing that logic in the game. I can't seem to figure out how I would implement that logic in the game.

Comment: Well something like `if (parseInt(dream.css('left')) < parseInt(angel.css('left'))) { angel.attr('src', 'angel_left.gif'); }`.  Without a working sample in jsFiddle or something it's too difficult to write working code.

Comment: Ok everything you said makes perfect scenes. Now how would that same logic work when the character (angel) has to move north east or south west?

Comment: I think it's fairly obvious, but to point you in the right direction: if `N = (angel.top < dream.top)` and `E = (angel.left < dream.left)` then `NE = N && E`

Comment: Thank you soo much. You really clarified how I am going to do this.

Thanks again :)